# Priority for compounded words in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to improve  my search results using Solr.
currently i am working on compounded words, so far i am getting results for the compounded word and its parts but the problem is that there is no prioity/weight between the results.
i would like to have the results relating to the original compounded word have higher weight/prioity that the its parts.
is there a way to do this with Solr ?

As an exsample the searchword might be "støvsuger", currently i am getting equal results for "støvsuger", "støv" and "suger". What i would like is the that "støvsuger" is higher weighted than "støv and "suger".

this is what i am currently doing:

```
<filter class="solr.DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory" minSubwordSize="4" dictionary="lang/ordbog.txt" onlyLongestMatch="true" maxSubwordSize="15" minWordSize="7"/>
```

The current querystring  looks like this:

```
{0}Portal1_{1}_{2}/select?defType=edismax
&fl=id,title,shortDescription,htmlContent,kbId,score
&mm={3}
&q={4}
&qf=_priorityKeywords^60 title^80 portalTitle^60 shortDescription^50 htmlContent^20
&pf=_priorityKeywords^60 title^100 portalTitle^60 shortDescription~10^50 htmlContent~10^20
&rows=500
&wt=json
&tie=0.1
```

Where the you can ingore {0}, {1}, {2}, and the {3} is the number of search words and {4} is the search word/term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have one field with the content without the compound word token filter and one field *with* the compound word token filter. Boost hits in the field without the compound word token filter more than hits in the one with (I'll just assume we're talking about a category here, but it'd work the same for any text referring to vacuum cleaners in your case):

```
qf=category_without_compounds^5 category_with_compounds
```

.. will give a 5x weight to any hits in the field without the expanded compound words. You can also give an even larger boost to exact hits (where the search query matches the a category or title exactly, for example).

You define a `copyField` instruction in your schema / collection configuration to copy the same content into both fields automagically.